# Unable to deploy API bundle on Apigee using Maven (apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0)

Tags: maven, apigee

I am unable to deploy an API to Apigee Using Maven (apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0). Following is the command I am using to deploy the bundle to my org on Apigee:

```
mvn install -P${envname} -Dapigee_URL=${apigeeURL} -Dapigee_USERNAME=${ApigeeUsername} -Dapigee_PASSWORD=${ApigeePassword} -Dapigee_ORG=${APIGEE_ORG} -Dapigee_OPTIONS=override -Dproject=${PROJECT} -Dapigee_envs=${ENV} -Dapigee.config.options=update
```

I notice that build (zip file) is created properly inside target folder, but it's not getting deployed on apigee.

I am getting the following error:

```
Request prepared for the server     
 **************************    
POST  https://localhost:4040/v1/organizations/test-org/environments/test/apis/test_api/revisions/1/deployments    
accept: application/json    
accept-encoding: gzip    
authorization: Basic [Not shown in log]    
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8    
 [Request body]    
override=true&delay=5    
[INFO]     
Waiting to assert bundle activation.....    
[ERROR] Deployment failed to activate    
[ERROR] Deployment failed: Bundle did not activate within expected time. Please check deployment status manually before trying again    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------    
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------    
[INFO] Total time: 18.402 s    
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-05T01:12:15+03:00    
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/297M    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------    
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (deploy-bundle-step) on project test_api: : MojoExecutionException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Deployment failed: Bundle did not activate within expected time. Please check deployment status manually before trying again
```

What could be the various reasons for this? Also please suggest the work around.

This is detailed error log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (deploy-bundle-step) on project test_api: : MojoExecutionException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Deployment failed: Bundle did not activate within expected time. Please check deployment status manually before trying again -> [Help 1]    
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (deploy-bundle-step) on project test_api:     
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)    
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:     
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.processHelpfulErrorMessage (DeployMojo.java:343)    
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:328)    
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)    
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Deployment failed: Bundle did not activate within expected time. Please check deployment status manually before trying again    
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.rest.RestUtil.activateBundleRevision (RestUtil.java:641)    
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.doActivateBundle (DeployMojo.java:227)    
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:273)    
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)   
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)   
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)    
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Deployment failed: Bundle did not activate within expected time. Please check deployment status manually before trying again    
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.rest.RestUtil.activateBundleRevision (RestUtil.java:613)    
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.doActivateBundle (DeployMojo.java:227)    
    at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:273)    
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)   
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)    
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)    
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)    
[ERROR]     
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.    
[ERROR]     
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:    
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Looks like it's posting to https://localhost:4040/v1/organizations/test-org/environments/test/apis/test_api/revisions/1/deployments which doesn't seem right to me. Can you share the pom.xml?

Comment: It appears the host is not set correctly under the profiles in your pom.xml.